# free malloc pointer locality issue

Tags: c, pointers, reference, local

I am trying to implement a function set_it_free as shown below, but it would only play with the pointer locally, which does not do what I want, i.e. free and set to null for a pointer. Could you help me to modify my set_it_free to make it work?

```
int set_it_free(void* pointer, unsigned long level, char* message){
logMessage(level, message);
assert  (pointer != NULL);  //Never free a NULL pointer
free    (pointer);          //Free a malloc/calloc/realloc pointer
pointer = NULL;             //Set it to NULL for prevention
return 0;}
```

I would call it like this in main()

```
int* a = (int* )malloc(sizeof(int));
set_it_free(a);
```

Comment: What ate you trying to do? If you have multiple variables for same memory then you will have to set all to `NULL`.

Comment: OT: Per the C-Standard `free()` does accept `NULL`, so there in fact is no need to assert `pointer` isn't `NULL`. However this test might be necessary for some **ancient** compilers.

Answer (score 2):

```
int set_it_free(void** ppointer, unsigned long level, char* message)
{
    logMessage(level, message);
    assert  ( ppointer != NULL);  //Check valid parameter
    assert  (*ppointer != NULL);  //Never free a NULL pointer
    free    (*ppointer);          //Free a malloc/calloc/realloc pointer
    *ppointer = NULL;             //Set it to NULL for prevention
    return 0;
}
```

And example usage:

```
sometype* pMyVar = malloc(somesize);
set_it_free(&pMyVar, 5, "freeing myVar");
```

Comment: In addition to my comment to the OP on testing for `NULL`-pointers: In this answer's code asserting `ppointer` itself isn't `NULL` would indeed make sense.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in C you should not cast the return values of functions returning `void *` (like `malloc`). It can cause subtle runtime problems if you forget to include the correct header files.

Secondly, when you pass the pointer `pointer` to the function, the pointer itself is passed by value, meaning the pointer is copied and any assignment to the local copy inside `set_it_free` will be only local. This means the assignment to `NULL` inside the function is only done to the local `pointer` variable, the pointer `a` will still point to the now unallocated memory once the function returns.

For the last problem there are four ways of solving this: The first is to pass the pointer by reference (as in the answer by abelenky), the other is to return the new pointer (similar to what `realloc` does). The third way is to assign to `a` after the function call, either `NULL` or make it point to something else. The fourth way is to simply not use the variable `a` again.